# Is there an eye dropper tool in google chrome's dev tool?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, color-picker

I want to get a color from a website using google chrome's dev tool.

I know that you can get the color code if it's set in the css, but I want to get a color from for example an image.

Is this possible with google chrome's dev tool?

Comment: @wOxxOm Wow, great! Do you want to answer this question so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Inspect a node](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/dom/#inspect) in the DOM Tree.

   [image: DOM Tree]
2. Click its `color` property to open the Color Picker. [Add a `color` property to the node](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/#declarations) if it doesn't have one.

   [image: color property]
3. Hover your mouse over the viewport.

   [image: eyedropper]
4. Click when you're hovering over the color that you want to sample.

Answer (score 2):

## Using [EyeDropper API](https://github.com/WICG/eyedropper-api/)

1. Option + ⌘ + J (macOS) or Shift + CTRL + J (Windows/Linux).
2. `await new EyeDropper().open();`
3. Hover over the color you want and tap on it
4. The hex value will be Printed into the console.

[image: https://twitter.com/tomayac/status/1432969851811794944?s=20]

[Source](https://twitter.com/tomayac/status/1432969851811794944?s=20)